# What's wrong with my gitignore file because I shouldn't see unstaged files in Commit upon test execution (no code change)?

Tags: commit, gitignore

I can't seem to get the gitignore file right or something because I shouldn't see unstaged files in Commit upon test execution (no code change).

Thanks in advance for your help,
Tien

Comment: what happened to my attachment/image?

Answer (score 0):

let's try posting the image/attachment again:
[image]